# Upgrading from SSD to M.2

Tags: upgrade, drive

I'm planning to upgrade the main drive containing root and boot stuff. Currently Ubuntu 16.04 is installed in SSD, and Ubuntu 18.04 is gonna be installed in the new M.2 drive.

I've heard that when upgrading from HDD to SSD, cloning is not a good idea. So, I doubt cloning SSD to M.2 would be okay with the same reason. Is it better to clean install in M.2 than cloning it? If not, after cloning it the OS upgrade to 18.04 is possible?

I'm afraid I have to do everything from scratch all over again. I don't know how much speed boost I get from hardware upgrading, but I have to upgrade the OS for the latest Gimp upgrade. So if I have to get headache anyway I'll do things all together. That's why this question looks complicated. Any idea is welcome really. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it will be faster and less painful to install 18.04 directly and then install your programs than cloning the ssd and then upgrading. You will have the bonus of a clean system. If you have a backup of your /home, you can easily get back the configs.

Comment: RoVo So you think cloning is okay from SSD to M.2?

Comment: I don't know because even if it was no problem I'd opt for a reinstall

Comment: @Smile cloning is never a problem. Even from hdd to ssd besides  you might have a larger hdd than ssd (and then it wont fit ;-))  Linux is smart enoiugh to see it is on an sdd and will start the trim systemd unit. I do agree with RoVo: a new install is probably quicker.

Comment: @Rinzwind alright a new install. I knew it this would be quite a task. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Another bit of advice: prepare for a reinstall and life becomes a lot easier. Put / and /home on the main disk. Make a named partition and put your personal stuff on there. Edit .config/user-dirs.dirs to point to the partition. Reinstall is format / and format of /home or a mount of /home if you want to keep settings and a mount of the partition for personal data. I have been doing that with my ssd+hdd combo notebook and a reinstall takes me less than 15 min + 5 minutes adding software I like to use.

Comment: @Rinzwind /home is a separate mount. I thought I may re-use it after installation.